# Capture video in any image format in WinRT

Tags: video, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I was working on the Media Capture example for WinRT from Windows dev center, which uses MediaCapture and MFT:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622

For my application I need images in **MFVideoFormat_NV12** format. But the **getGUID** method of **IMFMediaType** returns **MFVideoFormat_YUY2** as **MF_MT_SUBTYPE**.

I don't want to do the conversion between the two formats. Is there any way to set the image format for capturing video?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame capture type by the following API --

hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType)

available on the following link of microsoft. Moreover you can see the supported video capture format of your video capture device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to create/get an instance of IMFMediaSource for WinRT. It seems this is not supported for WinRT.